# Postgresql Invalid date format error

Tags: postgresql

In my postgresql query I am getting this error:

```
Error: SQL Error: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "'"
```

The log_field2 field is a varchar datatype and I did a cast to date (::date) and then checked the values in the parameters called {START_DATE} and {END_DATE} and put those in single quotes but to no avail.  Can someone please provide some direction/help as to what the problem might be?  Any help is appreciated.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT sle.source_id, 
count(sle.*),
sum(coalesce(log_field20::numeric, 0)) || ' min' as duration_total
FROM custom_field_log_entries sle 
INNER JOIN student_enrollment se 
ON (sle.source_id=se.student_id and se.custom_9 is null 
AND se.syear = {SYEAR} 
AND se.end_date is null)
INNER JOIN schools sc on (se.school_id=sc.id) 
WHERE sle.field_id = 328
**AND log_field2::date BETWEEN '{START_DATE}' AND '{END_DATE}'**
AND (log_field20 ~ '^[0-9]+$' or log_field20 is null) --{SCHOOL_SPECIFIC} 
AND se.school_id = {SCHOOL_ID}
GROUP BY sle.source_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You must change {SYEAR},'{START_DATE}', '{END_DATE}' to some value:

```
SELECT sle.source_id, 
       count(sle.*),
       sum(coalesce(log_field20::numeric, 0)) || ' min' as duration_total
 FROM custom_field_log_entries sle 
INNER JOIN student_enrollment se 
        ON (sle.source_id=se.student_id and se.custom_9 is null 
           AND se.syear = 2017 
           AND se.end_date is null)
INNER JOIN schools sc ON (se.school_id=sc.id) 
WHERE sle.field_id = 328
     AND log_field2::date BETWEEN '2017-01-10' AND '2017-01-25'
     AND (log_field20 ~ '^[0-9]+$' or log_field20 is null) --{SCHOOL_SPECIFIC} 
     AND se.school_id = 1 -- {SCHOOL_ID}
GROUP BY sle.source_id
```

Comment: I am passing in values from a PHP page. Sorry I should have clarified that.